# Language around Pointwise convergence v. Uniform convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

I've heard uniform convergence described loosely as convergence "occurring at the same rate at every point." Is that really accurate? If the absolute difference between a member of a sequence of functions and the function to which that sequence converges pointwise can be represented by a function of the point with a finite maximum, then isn't it true that the sequence of functions uniformly convergent AND the rate of convergence varies with the point?

Comment: It doesn't technically mean that they converge at the same rate, it's just loose language.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given an $\epsilon>0$ and $x$, we can define $N_x(\epsilon)$ as the smallest $N$ such that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N.$

In some sense, $N_x(\epsilon)$ is a measure of the rate convergence at $x.$

Uniform convergence means that for any $\epsilon>0,$ $N(\epsilon)=\sup_{x} N_x(\epsilon)<+\infty.$

So this doesn't strictly mean they converge at the same speed, but that there is *some* speed of convergence which is slower than (or equal to) all of them.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it would be more accurate to say "convergence *bounded* by some rate at every point." You are right that the convergence rate may be faster in some places than others. For instance, the function $f_n(x)=x^n$ on $[0,1/2]$ converges to $f \equiv 0$ uniformly, since $\sup_{x \in [0,1/2]}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=|f_n(x)| \le 2^{-n}$. But at $x=1/4$, the rate of convergence is the faster $4^{-n}$.

The point of the definition of uniform convergence is to exclude cases where the convergence at some points is arbitrarily slow.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like an acceptable translation in English of "for all $\varepsilon$ there is $n$ such that, for all $m>n$ and for all $x$, $\lvert f(x)-f_m(x)\rvert<\varepsilon$", though it might be misinterpreted in a set-up where a theory of "rates of convergence" has been introduced. If the reader understands it like this, it's ok. Otherwise he'd be misled. A possible misintepretation might be like this: if we say that a sequence $a_n$ "converges to $a$ like $n^{-2}$" if $\limsup_{n\to\infty} n^2\lvert a-a_n\rvert<+\infty$, then there are sequences of functions $f_n$ such that $f_n(x)$ converges to $f(x)$ like $n^{-2}$ for all $x$, *but* $f_n$ does not converge uniformly to $f$; on the other hand, your phrasing strongly hints towards the former.

What the formulation would like you to think is that there is a function $\varepsilon(n)$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \varepsilon(n)\to 0$ and such that for all $x$, $\lvert f(x)-f_n(x)\rvert<\varepsilon(n)$. In this sense, there is a "global" rate of convergence. But *globality* is the important part: you want a single bound holding for all $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Let's call the sequence $f_n$ and the limit $f$. If $f_n\to f$ uniformly, it's true that $f_n(x)-f(x)$ will not generally be constant in $x$ for any given $n$, but we have a uniform (in $x$) bound on the difference $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ that goes to zero as $n\to \infty$. That upper bound is what people mean by a uniform rate of convergence. The convergence at some points $x$ may be faster, but the convergence is *at least as fast* as the uniform rate at every point.

Answer (score 1):

Its not totally true to say that the points converge "at the same rate." First, "the same rate" isn't really a mathematical statement. Second, a better descriptor, in my opinion, is that the points converge in some similar fashion.

The definition of uniform convergence is that, for a given error bound $\epsilon$, there is eventually an $f_N$ for which all of the $f_n$'s beyond this point are within the error bound.[image]

Once you understand this, it is almost hard to think of a function which is *not* uniformly convergent. In a sense, a sequence has to behave badly for this to happen. Take $\{1/(nx)\}$ converging to $0$ on $(0,1]$, for example.